# Launch appium test on stand-alone real device

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am writing an automation script on android. My task is to open chrome browser, open a page, login, fill up form1, submit, fill another form2, submit and logout.

I can automate this via appium test that gets launched on real device and  all the setup/code is on my laptop. I would like to actually package everything in apk and install it on the real device and then run this script/test in stand-alone mode on the device. Essentially, would like to launch this script/test when the device is not connected to the laptop.

How can I achieve this.